# Mailchimp API PHP: 500 Error

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to make php code that will unsubscribe/subscribe users with given email.

I found this tutorial:
http://www.sutanaryan.com/2016/10/mailchimp-api-subscribe-or-unsubscribe-user-php-script/

But I am still getting error. I think that there is a problem in this file:

> require('mailchimp/Mailchimp.php');

In error log there's nothing.

Can anybody give me advice how to troubleshoot it or solve it in different way? I am beginner with almost no knowledge about PHP.

Thank you

Comment: What error are you actually getting?

Comment: Turn on error reporting for php. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: Thank you for quick replies, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it by this simple code, no other library is needed!

```
<?php

function rudr_mailchimp_subscriber_status( $email, $status, $list_id, $api_key, $merge_fields = array('FNAME' => '','LNAME' => '') ){
    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => $api_key,
            'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => $status,
        'merge_fields'  => $merge_fields
    );
    $mch_api = curl_init(); // initialize cURL connection

    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($data['email_address'])));
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode( 'user:'.$api_key )));
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the API response
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); // method PUT
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) ); // send data in json

    $result = curl_exec($mch_api);
    return $result;
}

$email = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$status = 'subscribed'; // "subscribed" or "unsubscribed" or "cleaned" or "pending"
$list_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX'; // where to get it read above
$api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // where to get it read above
$merge_fields = array('FNAME' => 'Misha','LNAME' => 'Rudrastyh');

rudr_mailchimp_subscriber_status($email, $status, $list_id, $api_key, $merge_fields );


?>
```

Comment: Hey in case it wasn't clear why your method works, the "merge_fields" key looks like it used to be "merge_vars" which caused a 500 error for me as well... I can't prove anything per say but I suspect that changed at some point in MC and they just decide to return a useless 500 error instead of something we can use. We had this integrated years ago then all of a sudden it broke. I seriously doubt some rogue programmer just went in and changed that one property.